# Swift Show Overlapping Button on TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a button in a TableViewCell the overlaps the welcome TableViewCell.  It looks fine when the view loads, however when I scroll down the tableview and scroll back up the button is cut off by the next tableviewcell.

I found a hack to make the background clear for the message TableViewCell, however, the bottom of the button is still not clickable.

Is there a way to set the priority of the button to be on top of the next?

[image]

[image]

HomeTableViewController.swift

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "heroCell", for: indexPath) as! HeroTableViewCell
        heroCell = cell
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10000, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "welcomeCell", for: indexPath) as! WelcomeTableViewCell
        // Set Intro Name
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            // User is signed in

            // References to firebase
            let userFS = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")

            // Set the navigation title to users name
            userFS.document(user.uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
                if let userInfo = document {
                    let firstName = userInfo["firstName"] as! String
                    cell.introLabel.text = "Hey, \(firstName)"
                } else {
                    print("User name does not exist")
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tripsCell", for: indexPath) as! TripTableViewCell
        return cell
    case 3:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "suggestionsCell", for: indexPath) as! SuggestionTableViewCell
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "popularsCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: return 425
    case 1: return 200
    case 2: return 400
    case 3: return 400
    default: return 400
    }
}

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 425
}
```

HeroTableViewCell.swift

```
class HeroTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var heroImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var heroImageViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var planTripButton: SpringButton!

// MARK: - Variables
let notification = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()

override func awakeFromNib() {
}

// MARK: - Actions
@IBAction func addTripButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    planTripButton.animation = "pop"
    planTripButton.animate()
    notification.notificationOccurred(.success)
}

}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: override `willDisplayCell` and call `bringViewToFront`.

Comment: Can you please share cellforrowheight method ?

Comment: added the height

Comment: change default to 425.and check

Comment: @pmanning now try my answer. it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want + button to hover over the UITableView, so that it is clickable regardless of which cell the user has scrolled to?

In the image below, I have place my action button (the pencil in the top right of the view) at the same level in the view hierarchy as my tableView.  So as the user scrolls, that button is always visible and the user can click at any time.

Please note where the Action Button sits relative to the tableView in the Document outline.  It is at the same level.  It is not a subview of the tableView.

[image]

Comment: tried with tableview, tableviewcells and the content views for both cells...still occuring

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit.  Perhaps this is what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't have the View in the hierarchy because I'm using a tableviewcontroller.  Therefore it won't allow me to put the button on the same level